# No hot water from the hot side of the faucet for entire home

Tags: hot-water

I am having hot water issue with my home. I can feel the hot water outflow pipe from the hot water heater being hot. But when I turn on the hot tap, the water turns from enventually cold.

In addition, when i completely turn off the the how water valve coming out from water heater, there is still some cold water coming out from the hot side of the faucet after leaving it on for 5 minutes. I am not sure if there is a crossover of cold water to hot water side. Please advise.

Comment: Has there been any plumbing changes like new water heater or recirculation pump added?

Comment: Is your hot water heater gas or electric? How old is it?

Comment: No my hot water heater is tankless and has been installed for the past 5 years. It just started to give me problems starting few weeks backs.

Comment: All taps?  Just one tap?  Or one room?  Had similar issue, but it was my furthest bathroom shower faucet